# Do I have to lock std::queue when getting size?

Tags: c++, queue, locking

I'm using `std::queue` in a multithreaded environment. Other threads may modify the queue as they wish. At some point I would like to call `std::queue::size()`. Do I have to lock the queue for that call? Will something bad happen if I don't?

Comment: You might read the wrong size, also you might never read the right size as the optimizer may detect that your reading thread never updates the size and therefore optimizes out the read.

Comment: even if you lock when getting the size, what use can you make of that information in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, it's an approximation of the size of the queue. I can use that info for monitoring.

Comment: @RichardCritten For statistical purposes it doesn't matter whether the size is 100% correct. As long as it is not corrupted, as in some garbage value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is undefined behavior and anything can happen. Behavior is undefined when one thread accesses an object while another thread is, or might be, modifying it.

I hesitate to add this because whether or not you can think of a way it can fail is not relevant. It's not defined, period. But just in case someone argues there's no imaginable way it could fail: Consider a queue that dynamically allocates a control structure that contains the size of the queue and information about each object in the queue. When the queue is enlarged, a new control structure might be allocated, the old structure freed, and a pointer updated. A concurrent call to `size` might grab the old pointer and then access it after it's freed and possibly contains completely different information or even has been removed from the memory map.

Comment: But please, learn the most important lesson -- it doesn't matter whether or not you can think of a way it can fail. Things fail all the time in ways that people did not think of at the time. Follow the rules and write code that's guaranteed to work by the relevant standards/specifications.

Answer (score -9):

Just reading the size isn't going to be an issue in itself. You're going to read a single memory location. You might read the *wrong* size, because a change in the size made by another thread might not yet be visible in this thread, but you're not going to read a corrupted value. Such as half the bits from one value and the other from another value.

Comment: How do you know that it's going to read a single memory location? Have you seen the OP's implementation of `std::queue`?

Comment: 'Such as half the bits from one value and the other from another value'  -  That's exactly something that can happen; in fact more than that, you could read bits that aren't in either value too; maybe the compiler zero's the memory when it writes a number.